# How to connect two rectangles, or alternatively, how to make nodes wider and longer than the text

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to translate a graphic in a book, and I need to connect some rectangles to do so. Here's what I have so far:

[image]

As you can see, the position of the arrow is not pleasant looking because the arrows don't connect to the edges of the rectangles. The code that generated this graphic:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [rounded corners, fill=lightgray] (3,0) rectangle (6,-1) node (1) [pos=.5] {\textit{Output} gráfico} ;

\draw [rounded corners, fill=lightgray] (3,-2.5) rectangle (6,-3.5) node (2) [pos=.5] {\textit{Game Manager}};

\draw [rounded corners, fill=lightgray] (3,-5) rectangle (6,-6) node (3) [pos=.5] {Jogador};

\draw (-0.5,-1) rectangle (2,-2.5) node (4) [pos=.5, align=center] {Descrições de \\ jogos};

\draw (-0.5,-3) rectangle (2,-4.5) node (5) [pos=.5, align=center] {Registro de \\ partidas};

\draw (7,-2.5) rectangle (9,-3.5) node (6) [pos=.5, align=center] {Registro de \\ partidas};

 \draw[black, thick, ->]  (2) --  (1.south);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

I think it would be better to do this with nodes, since nodes connect to the borders, but I can't get nodes to look like the rectangles in the picture above. They're small and have no borders. Here's an example:

[image]

And the code that generated the graphic above:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node [ rounded corners, fill=lightgray] at (4.5,0) (1) {\textit{Output} gráfico};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

So my questions are: How can I connect two rectangles with arrows that start and end at edges? If that's not possible, how can I generate larger nodes with visible borders (but the font size remaning the same)?

Comment: `text width=<dimension>`, `text height=<dimension>`, `text depth=<dimension>`, `minimum height=<dimension`, `minimum width=<dimension>` ?? Or `inner sep=<dimension>`, `inner xsep=`, `inner ysep` ...

Comment: Please edit your question to make your code compilable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have time right now to redo the entire MWE, but the first rectangle can be replaced by:

```
\node (1) [rounded corners, draw, fill=lightgray,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm]
   at (4.5,-.5) {\textit{Output} gr\'afico} ;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the keys `minimum height` and `minimum width` for the size of the nodes, and use the library `positioning` to place them. Then use styles for every type of node.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=15 mm and 15 mm,
                    every node/.style={draw},
                    central/.style={fill=lightgray,rounded corners,minimum           
                                    width=3cm,minimum height=1cm},
                    other/.style={text width=2.2 cm,text centered,minimum 
                                  width=2.5cm,,minimum height=1.5cm}]  
\node[central] (output){\textit{Output} gr\'afico};
\node[central] (manager) [below=of output] {\textit{Game Manager}};
\node[central] (jogador) [below=of manager] {Jogador};
\node[text width= 2cm,text centered] [right=of manager] {Registro de \\ partidas};
\node[other,yshift=-1cm] [left=of manager]{Registro de \\ partidas};
\node[other,yshift=1.2cm] [left=of manager]{Descri\c c\=oes de \\ jogos};
\draw[->] (manager)--(output);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```